# Covariance of Brownian motion intuition

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, covariance

So the covariance between two time-instances of Brownian motion is $$\text{Cov}(B_s, B_t) = \min(s,t).$$

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273437/brownian-motion-and-covariance) gives a derivation of this fact, but I'm lacking intuition.

Suppose $\epsilon \ll 1 $ is small and $t$ is larger. Then
$$ \text{Cov}(B_\epsilon, B_t) = \epsilon,$$
$$\text{Cov}(B_{t+\epsilon}, B_{2t}) = t+\epsilon.$$

In both cases the time step is $t-\epsilon$, but the covariances are drastically different.

Brownian motion is stationary, so why is this true? (And if not, what am I doing wrong?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you are saying $X-Y$ and $Z-W$ has the same distribution, why $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$ can be very different from $\mathrm{Cov}(Z,W)$? Think of a baby example: $X$ has some distribution with large variance, take $Y = X+ c$, where $c$ is a constant. Now say $Z$ has some distribution with small variance, take $W = Z+ c$. Can you see that $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$ can be much larger than $\mathrm{Cov}(Z,W)$?

Comment: Thanks! For my own reference, you're saying $X= B_{t+\epsilon}$ has greater variance than $Z = B_{\epsilon}$,  and adding a constant $c \sim \mathcal{N}(0, t-\epsilon)$ to both, the covariance of the former still has greater covariance than the latter...  since $Cov(X,X+c) = E[X(X+c)] - E[X]E[X+c] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 = Var(X) > Var(Z) = Cov(Z,Z+c)$

Comment: You are on a good track! In my example, $c$ is some absolute constant, but you can think of $c$ as having some fixed distribution as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your computation is correct. However, Brownian motion itself is not a stationary process. It's *increments* are though. This means that for for any $\epsilon>0$, the process $\{B_{t+\epsilon}-B_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ is stationary, ie has the same distribution. In particular by setting $t=0$ we get that $B_{t+\epsilon}-B_t$ is equal in distribution to $B_\epsilon-B_0$ and hence to $B_\epsilon$.

Comment: Right, $B_{2t} - B_{t+\epsilon}$ has the same distribution as $B_t - B_\epsilon$. So why are the covariances so different?

Comment: How did you define Brownian motion?